# SQLMAP is not working

Tags: sql, database, web-applications, sqlmap

I recently installed sqlmap, when I try to run the command to inject the database of a website, it opens up the python file "sqlmap.py" instead of showing the available databases.

Comment: Do other Python files on the same server run correctly?

Comment: @TrippKinetics I'm new to SQL map and I'm currently only willing to retrieve the database from a website. I used the command "sqlmap.py -u <url to the webpage> --dbs". I don't know about other files.

Comment: I can't help you without more diagnostic steps.  Please let me know if any other Python is able to run on your web server.

Comment: @TrippKinetics I tried running sqlmapapi.py even that's not running.

Comment: It looks like your web server is not configured to run Python.

Comment: Let me tell you what I did:
1. Installed the latest version of python from python.org
2. Installed the sqlmap zip file 
3. Copied the extracted file to the python27 folder.
4. Created a shortcut on the desktop and specified the target location to  "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" and start in location to "C:\Python27\SQLMap"
Now this is what I saw a guy did in a YouTube video and for him it worked. I have no idea why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Here are some instructions on how to make IIS run Python programs.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/276494/using-python-scripts-with-iis